# fullscreen alert dialog with image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a custom alert dialog with an image view attached to it and wanted to know if it was possible to increase the size of the dialog and image to fit the whole screen?  If so how would you do this?

```
private void loadPhoto(String filepath, int xmlView, int layoutView, int imageView){

    //Bitmap operations
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);

    //calculate the inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleImageSize(options, 128, 96);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

     AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     //inflate the view
     View layout = inflater.inflate(xmlView, 
             (ViewGroup)findViewById(layoutView));

     ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(imageView);
     image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options));
     imageDialog.setView(layout);
     imageDialog.setPositiveButton("Return", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

     imageDialog.create();
     imageDialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fill almost the whole screen, don't use Dialog, this is not the purpose for that class. You can try instead with PopupWindow class, a very customizable floatting container.

Comment: This sounds very interesting!  I shall research upon this

Answer (score 1):

If you want full screen dialog, it would probably be much easier to just make and use separate Activity for that purpose instead - you would benefit from Activity flexibility and do not need to bother dialog limitations.

Comment: is it then possible to make the image fill around 80 percent of the screen along with the dialog options at the bottom?

Comment: Sure. It's normal activity. Do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Marcin Orlowski, maybe an Activity would be better but if you still want to use the dialog, to make it full screen just need to set the proper style when you create it. By default, the dialog is created with the `Theme.Dialog` but you can change it. All you need to do is this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.Theme_DeviceDefault_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
```

Change that line in your code and you should see you dialog fill the screen

Comment: when I try to do context.  there is no option for android to be selected

Comment: Please check again the answer. There was a mistake, there should be a comma instead of period after `context`